# Can not use -m multi threading with ** in gsutil rm

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

Using gustil, I want to delete all objects in a bucket. But I do not want to delete the bucket. The job takes about 2 minutes and I would like to speed it up with the -m option for multi threading.

However, when I try `gsutil -m rm -a gs://dls-qa/**` I get 'CommandException: Incorrect option(s) specified'. Am I not allowed to use -m with the double asterisk ** which is required to keep the bucket?

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rm

Comment: Can you try this, if you are using Linux use single quoting, if windows use double quoting. For example: `gsutil -m rm -a 'gs://dls-qa/**'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the same command and it worked in my case :

```
gsutil -m rm -a "gs://mazlum_test/**"
```

I added `"` chars in my `bucket` pattern because I am using `omyzsh`

Maybe you have to upgrade your `gcloud` sdk version.

Comment: That did it, thanks! I needed to double quote to preserve the glob. I guess it has to do with the multi threads with forked shells.